# What is a technique to animate objects from sprite sheet in OpenGL ES Android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, 2d

Because of performance I moved to OpenGL ES 2D from `canvas.drawBitmap`

This is sprite sheet 4x1:

[image]

Now to make it work I had followed class:

```
public Vulcan(ScreenObjectsView objectsView, int vulkanSpriteID, Context context) {     

    this.b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), vulkanSpriteID);

    // 1x4
    height = b.getHeight();
    width = b.getWidth()/4;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    x = display.getWidth()/2-width/2;  // deprecated
    y = display.getHeight()-height;  // deprecated  

}

public void update() {
    frameFreq++;

    if(frameFreq > 0){
        currentFrame = ++currentFrame % 4;
        frameFreq = 0;
    }       
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();

    int srcX = currentFrame * width;

    Rect  src = new Rect(srcX, 0, srcX+width, height);
    Rect  dst = new Rect(x, y, x+width, y+height);

    canvas.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, null);
}
```

Each period of time I take `Rect` and shift from left to right (in loop):

```
currentFrame = ++currentFrame % 4;
```

So far so good.

How can I animate above mentioned sprite sheet in in OpenGL ES?

Today, I know how to draw and move objects in OpenGL ES (thanks to [good demo](http://blog.terryprobert.co.uk/2012/03/17/android-game-development-quest-pt-4-animating-the-sprites/))

but don't know to play with sprites.

Any ideas, links, snippets of code?

**[Edit]**

Ther is no mater to use sprite sheet or 4 images like:

[image]  , [image] and so on.

Strange that still didn't get any answer or direction.

Thank you,

**[Edit 2]**

According to what Aert says I implemented the following code and it works.

**But it seems messy**

Too much code for OpenGL ES. For each texture (I have 4), I need create FloatBuffer:

Maybe someone have shorter way, or I did something wrong.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class DevQuestSpriteBase {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "Fess";//DevQuestSpriteBase.class.getSimpleName();

protected int mFrame = 0;
protected int mSwitcher = 0;
private int textureCount = 1; // frame animation
protected int[] textures = new int[textureCount]; // frame animation

// texture and verts
protected FloatBuffer vertexBuffer,
textureBuffer1,
textureBuffer2,
textureBuffer3,
textureBuffer4;

ByteBuffer bb1;

protected float vertices[] = {
        0f,0f,0.0f,
        1f,0f,0.0f,
        0f,1f,0.0f,
        1f,1f,0.0f
};


/** 1 frame */
protected float texture1[] = {          
        0.0f, 1.0f,     
        0.0f, 0.0f,     
        0.25f, 1.0f,    
        0.25f, 0.0f     
};
/** 2 frame */
protected float texture2[] = {          

        0.25f, 1.0f,        
        0.25f, 0.0f,        
        0.5f, 1.0f,     
        0.5f, 0.0f      
};
/** 3 frame */
protected float texture3[] = {          
        0.5f, 1.0f,     
        0.5f, 0.0f,     
        0.75f, 1.0f,    
        0.75f, 0.0f     
};
/** 4 frame */
protected float texture4[] = { 
        0.75f, 1.0f,        
        0.75f, 0.0f,        
        1.0f, 1.0f,     
        1.0f, 0.0f      
};


public DevQuestSpriteBase(){
    // vertices buffer
    bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // texture buffer
    bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture1.length * 4);
    bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer1 = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer1.put(texture1);
    textureBuffer1.position(0);

    //#########################################################

    // texture buffer
    bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture2.length * 4);
    bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer2 = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer2.put(texture2);
    textureBuffer2.position(0);

    //#########################################################

    // texture buffer
    bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture3.length * 4);
    bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer3 = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer3.put(texture3);
    textureBuffer3.position(0);

    //#########################################################

    // texture buffer
    bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture4.length * 4);
    bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer4 = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer4.put(texture4);
    textureBuffer4.position(0);
}


private void update() {

    if(mSwitcher == 5){
        mFrame = ++mFrame % 4;
        mSwitcher = 0;
        // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "DevQuestSpriteBase :: " + mFrame);
    }
    else{
        mSwitcher++; 
    }   


}

public void draw(GL10 gl){

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);


    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    if(mFrame == 0){
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer1);
    }
    else  if(mFrame == 1){
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer2);
    }
    else  if(mFrame == 2){
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer3);
    }
    else  if(mFrame == 3){
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer4);
    }


    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "DevQuestSpriteBase :: draw"); 

    update();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    //gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer1);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}


public int[] getTextures() {
    return textures;
}
}
```

Comment: "*This is my sprite sheet 4x1:*" Isn't that *Doom's* sprite sheet?

Comment: Yep, i took it from Doom and added fire, "My" means in my application. Good catch, :), Im not GUI designer and for demo/development its enough,

Comment: once you had load your texture(the 4 picture in the same file) you can "crop" your texture before drawing it.

Comment: Can you give some example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into a lot of detail, you need to do the following (assuming you are already drawing a sprite using 4 vertices):

- Define the texture coordinates corresponding to the vertices of the sprite for each animation frame, e.g.

  ```
  texCoordsFrame1 = [0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f];
  ```
- Upload the spritesheet texture, e.g.

  ```
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
  ```
- Draw using the texture coordinates corresponding to the frame you want to show when required, e.g.

  ```
  ... 
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoordsFrame1);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
  ```

Alternatively, you can upload the separate frames as individual textures, but that is undesirable from a performance point of view.

There are a few gotcha's

- When using GLES1, you can only use power-of-two textures. In that case you'll have to scale the texture or increase its size to be power-of-two and adjust the texture coordinates.
- The bitmap vs GL y-coordinate direction difference is a bit confusing, and you might end up with a vertically flipped sprite.

Comment: I would also recommend using the [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) package, as it does a lot of this stuff [for you](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteAnimation).

Comment: Thank you mate, so from your response I got for spritesheet 4x1 I need create `texCoordsFrame1, texCoordsFrame2, ..3, ..4`. Right? I see you took only 1/4 of width, the question is where `texture[0])` refer to?

Comment: You can't use `glTexCoordPointer` its should be buffer.

Comment: Re. `glTexCoordPointer`: you're correct - did it off the top of my head. The `texture` holds the values generated from a call to [glGenTextures](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml). Did you get it working?